# sending binary data via POST on android

Tags: android, http, client

Android supports a limited version of apache's http client(v4).
typically if I want to send binary data using content type= application/octet-stream via POST,
I do the following:

```
              HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

              HttpPost method=new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.1:8080/xxx");
              System.err.println("send to server "+s);

              if(compression){
                  byte[]compressed =compress(s);
                  RequestEntity entity = new ByteArrayRequestEntity(compressed);  
                  method.setEntity(entity);

              }



              HttpResponse resp=client.execute(method);
```

however ByteArrayRequestEntity is not supported on android. what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`ByteArrayEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity.html).  [`ByteArrayRequestEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/ByteArrayRequestEntity.html) is from 3.x